# C#: How to manipulate a values of items in List<t>

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I use two List.
One is that a list is recorded commands, parameters and time.
another is same from first one. However, I will add timespan between two sequential commands.
I have a problem with moving a value to another list.
Also I don't know why I cannot use ToString method when I save a timespan value.
I could see the out out range exception.

```
 public class log
 {
     [XmlElement("command")]
     public int command { get; set; }
     [XmlElement("param")]
     public int param { get; set;}
     [XmlElement("time")]
     public string time { get; set; }
 }

List<log> logs_temp = new List<log>(1);
List<log> logs = new List<log>(logs_temp.Count);

log log_0 = new log();

log_0.command = 1;
log_0.param = 0;
log_0.time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");

logs_temp.Add(log_0);

// I got a out of range exception
for (int i = 0; i <=logs_temp.Count-1; i++)
{
     logs[i].param = logs_temp[i].command;
     logs[i].param = logs_temp[i].param;

     //Get a timespan between two sequencial command log

    TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan timespan = DateTime.Parse(logs_temp[i + 1].time).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(logs_temp[i].time));

    //add second value as string but cannot
    logs[i].time = timespan.ToString(@"ss"); 
}
```

Comment: your problem is that logs list have 1 element and logs_temp have 2 elements because of the  "logs_temp.Add(log_0);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must guarantee that both lists have the same size to run a loop like that. 
And if you are using values from the next position (i+1) you must check if it exists.
something like this:

```
List<log> logs_temp = new List<log>();
List<log> logs = new List<log>();
log log_0 = new log();
log_0.command = 1;
log_0.param = 0;
log_0.time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
logs_temp.Add(log_0);
logs.Add(new log());

for (int i = 0; i <= logs_temp.Count-1; i++)
{
    logs[i].param = logs_temp[i].command;
    logs[i].param = logs_temp[i].param;

    //Get a timespan between two sequencial command log
    if (i + 1 < logs_temp.Count)
    {
        TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan();
        TimeSpan timespan = DateTime.Parse(logs_temp[i + 1].time).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(logs_temp[i].time));

        //add second value as string but cannot
        logs[i].time = timespan.TotalSeconds.ToString(); 
    }
}
```